# ?Attr/color for Android < API21

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My app has multiple themes that are applied based on user preference, the app works fine on Android API => 21 and crashes in lower versions, I would like to support API 19 and above thus need your help.

**Attrs.xml**
Three Custom attributes are defined as below:

```
<resources>
        <declare-styleable name="da">
            <attr name="backgroundcolor" format="reference"/>
            <attr name="titletextcolor" format="reference"/>
            <attr name="textcolor" format="reference"/>
        </declare-styleable>
    </resources>
```

**Styles.xml**
Three Custom Themes that include the custom attributes are defined as below:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
            <item name="backgroundcolor">@color/colorWhite</item>
            <item name="titletextcolor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="textcolor">@color/colorBlack</item>
        </style>

        <style name="AppTheme1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary1</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark1</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent1</item>
            <item name="backgroundcolor">@color/colorWhite</item>
            <item name="titletextcolor">@color/colorPrimary1</item>
            <item name="textcolor">@color/colorBla`</item>
        </style>

        <style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary2</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark2</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent2</item>
            <item name="backgroundcolor">@color/colorWhite</item>
            <item name="titletextcolor">@color/colorPrimary2</item>
            <item name="textcolor">@color/colorBlack</item>
        </style>
```

**activity_nav.xml**
The custom attributes are used in multiple layout similar to the example below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="?attr/backgroundcolor"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/backgroundcolor"
        app:itemTextColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="?attr/colorPrimary"

        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_nav"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_nav_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**NavActivity.java**
User theme preference is called for onCreate as shown below:

```
 public class NavActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    SharedPreferences shared;
    ListView listView;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;

    ArrayList<Model> arrayList = new ArrayList<Model>();
    private int i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        shared = getSharedPreferences("Setting", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int myStyle = shared.getInt("myStyle",0);
        switch (myStyle){
            case 0:
                this.setTheme(R.style.NoActionBar);
                break;
            case 1:
                this.setTheme(R.style.NoActionBar1);
                break;
            case 2:
                this.setTheme(R.style.NoActionBar2);
                break;
            case 3:
                this.setTheme(R.style.NoActionBar3);
                break;
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        String [] title = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titels);
        String [] desc = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.desc);
        int icon = R.drawable.icon;

        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

        for (i =0 ; i<title.length; i++){
            Model modle = new Model(title[i],desc[i],icon);
            arrayList.add(modle);
        }

        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this,arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
}
```

**Error Log**
App works fine on versions =>21  and crashes in lower versions with the following error:

```
  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: www.alitkaan2.com, PID: 3098
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{www.alitkaan2.com/www.alitkaan2.com.NavActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:621)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
            at www.alitkaan2.com.NavActivity.onCreate(NavActivity.java:52)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
            at www.alitkaan2.com.NavActivity.onCreate(NavActivity.java:52) 
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:621)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:670)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:207)
            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:281)
            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:193)
            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:104)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
            at www.alitkaan2.com.NavActivity.onCreate(NavActivity.java:52) 
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:670) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
            at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:207) 
            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:281) 
            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:193) 
            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:104) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
            at www.alitkaan2.com.NavActivity.onCreate(NavActivity.java:52) 
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
         Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/side_nav_bar.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f08008f
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2101)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:470)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595) 
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:670) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
            at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:207) 
            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:281) 
            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:193) 
            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:104) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
            at www.alitkaan2.com.NavActivity.onCreate(NavActivity.java:52) 
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
        Caused b
    Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8628', transport: 'socket'
```

**I would like to support Android versions with API 19 and above thus need your help.**

Comment: What technology are you using? Version 19/21 of what? 12 is the latest version of the Java - it's the only tag in your question and not a word about anything else.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was due shapes

Can't use ?attr in shapes for < API 21

work around solution:
1. use @color in shapes instead of ?attr
2. create same shape in different colors as required.
3. add an attribute for the shape in attrs
4. add the attribute to theme and link it to the shape

This worked for API 19 and above

Answer (score 0):

you can use only #argb color or use @color/your_color in API<21 in xml drawable

Comment: It's important to take into consideration the context of the question and error to give a proper answer

Answer (score -2):

You can check your side_nav_bar line 18. There must be some mistake happened.

Comment: This is line 18:  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Comment: I am having the same problem only with API 19 in 4 different projects .. I suspect it's due to using ?attr

Comment: can you please upload the slide_nav_bar xml file

Comment: android could not find res/drawable/side_nav_bar.xml. Make sure u have this one.

Comment: I found the problem but don't know what the solution is ... The problem is using “?attr” to make shapes in drawable … everything seems to work if I use “color” instead but that does not solve my problem as I want the color to be dynamic in quite a few shaps for borders, background and buttons.

Here is a sample:

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="135"
        android:endColor="?attr/background"
        android:startColor="@color/white"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>

Comment: you should not use ?attr/backgraoud as endcolor. use a color instead like you used in start color.